# Boundedness in uniform spaces?

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

After looking a bit at uniform spaces, as their general definition seems relevant to the study of topological vector spaces, it seems that they provide just enough structure to define the notion of *total boundedness*:

> Say a set $B$ is *totally bounded* if for any entourage $V$, there are finitely many points $x_n$ such that $B \subseteq \bigcup_n V[x_n]$.

I haven't seen this definition explicitly, but I have seen a special case of it applied in the context of TVS, though not named as such. However, I can't seem to get a similar definition for boundedness proper. Specifying that $B$ be contained in some $V[x]$ just won't work, as the $V$ could be made arbitrarily large.

> Is it possible to get such a definition of boundedness in uniform spaces?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if $d$ denotes the euclidean distance on $\mathbb{R}$, don't $d$ and $d \wedge 1$ generate the same set of entourages, but different notions of boundedness?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by d∧1...

Comment: $\wedge$ denotes the minimum, so i mean the metric $\min\{d(\cdot, \cdot), 1\}$.

Comment: Ok, so how do they generate different notions of boundedness? Is it possible for a set to be bounded in one metric but not the other? And how to show they generate the same set of entourages?

Comment: The first metric admits unbounded sets [e.g. $\mathbb{R}$], but the second doesn't. Therein all sets have diameter at most $1$. It should be possible [with some tedious work] to show that they generate the same set of entourages. I didn't check this rigorously, that's why I commented instead of answering.

Comment: I've encountered the definition of a bounded set $A$ as a set such that for any entourage $V$ there is a number $n$ and a finite set $F$ such that 
$$
A\subseteq V^n(F)
$$
See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392322/closure-of-bounded-set-in-uniform-space and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399310/precompactness-and-boundedness-in-uniform-space

Comment: This question also is the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976712/bounded-uniform-space. I suggest once one of both receives an answer, the other one gets closed as a duplicate.

Comment: A reference is *Boundedness in uniform spaces, topological groups and homogeneous spaces* by C.J. Atkin, according the the OP of the questions I linked above.

Comment: One may define a set $A$ in a uniform space to be *bounded* if for any symmetric entourage $V$ there is a natural number $n$ and a finite set $F$ such that
$$
A \subseteq V^n(F)
$$
Assume $d$ is a metric on $X$ inducing the uniform structure $\cal U$. If $A$ is bounded in $(X,\cal U)$, then for any $ε>0$ there exists a number $n$ and a finite set $F$ such that $A⊆V_ε^n(F)$, where $V_ε$ is entourage containing all pairs $(x,y)$ such that $d(x,y)<ε$. By the triangle inequality, $A$ is then contained in 
$$
V_{nε}(F)⊆V_{nε+\max_{x\in F}(d(y,x))}(y)
$$
so $A$ is bounded in $(X,d)$

Comment: @Stefan Hamcke I know it's been awhile now, but would you be willing to collect all that into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.

Let $d_1$ be the euclidean metric on the real numbers and $d_2 = \min\{d_1(\cdot, \cdot), 1\}$. It is easy to check that $d_2$ satisfies all conditions of a metric and that all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are bounded. Therefore $d_1$ and $d_2$ induce different notions of boundedness in $\mathbb{R}$.

however, both metrics induce the same entourages. Consider for a metric $d$ the set $U_\alpha^d = \{(x, y) \mid d(x, y) < \alpha \}$. Then the set $\Phi^d = \{B \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \mid U_\alpha^d \subset B \text{ for some } \alpha > 0\}$ is an entourage for any metric $d$. Now if a set $M$ is in $\Phi^{d_1}$, then there is an $\alpha > 0$ with $U_\alpha^{d_1} \subset M$. We can wlog assume $\alpha < 1$ [by replacing $\alpha$ with $\min\{\alpha, \frac{1}{2}\}$] and therefore $U_\alpha^{d_1} = U_\alpha^{d_2}$, so $M \in \Phi^{d_2}$. In a similar fashion, the inclusion $\Phi^{d_2} \subset \Phi^{d_1}$ can be shown.

This means that $d_1$ and $d_2$ induce the same entourages on $\mathbb{R}$, but different notions of boundedness.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm going to try to sleep on this now, and if later the logic seems airtight, I'll accept it. Currently my brain is under the fog of insomnia.

Comment: Wait a second... the $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb R$, but the $U_\alpha^d$ are collections of ordered pairs. How can the latter be contained in the former?

Comment: My bad, the $B$ should be subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I've fixed the mistake now.

Comment: Also, the $\Phi^d$ is a _system_ of entourages, right?

Comment: Yes, it's the system that is induced by $d$.

Comment: Ok, so looking at this answer and also the comment by Stefan Hamcke, it seems the answer is _yes_, but the notion of boundedness will be weaker than that of whatever metric is placed on it. So one can say if $M$ is bounded in the uniform sense, it will be bounded in whatever metric is placed on $X$, but not necessarily the other way around.